# Hacer un if en html de un controlador

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy haciendo un buscador en vivo, lo estoy realizando en el controlador de Laravel, recibo la respuesta por AJAX y imprimo los resultados, pero quiero hacer un `if` para comprobar si existe una condición y si es así mostrar una imagen, pero no llevo bien la mezcla de lenguajes.

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $output = '<div class="col-12 result">';
            $products = DB::table('equipos')
                ->where('busqueda', 'LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")
                ->get();
            if(count($products) > 0)
                {
                foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
                    $output.=
                '<a href="'. route('app.verEquipo', $product->url) .'">
                    <div class="row espacioRowBusca">'.
                        '<div class="col-2 center"><img src='. asset("{$product->fotoPNG}") .' alt="" class="imgBuscador"></div>'.
                        '<div class="col-10">
                            <h3>'.$product->name.'</h3>
                            <p>'.Str::limit($product->descBusqueda, 100).'</p>
                            '. if($product->fda == 1){  .'
                                <img src='. asset({{ asset('images/logos/fda-mio.svg') }}) .' alt="" class="imgBuscador">
                            '}'
                        </div>'.
                    '</div>
                </a>';
                } // end foreach
                } else {
                    $output.= '<div class="noResultados">No se encontraron resultados</div>';
                } // end if
            $output.='</div>';
            return Response($output);
        }
}
```

Lo que llevo mal en concreto es esta parte, me da error de sintaxis:

```
'. if($product->fda == 1){  .'
   <img src='. asset({{ asset('images/logos/fda-mio.svg') }}) .' alt="" class="imgBuscador">
'}'
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar tus comillas dobles por simples `<img src='. asset({{ asset('images/logos/fda-mio.svg') }}) .' alt='' class='imgBuscador'>`

Comment: Hola @KaoX pero de por si ya da error el if sin poner la imagen, me da error de sintaxis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes concatenar e incluir condiciones, lo adecuado sería crear una variable previamente:

```
            foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
                // Asignar imagen o cadena vacía con asignación ternaria
                $img = ($product->fda == 1)
                    ? '<img src="'. asset({{ asset('images/logos/fda-mio.svg') }}) .'" alt="" class="imgBuscador">'
                    : '';
                $output.=
            '<a href="'. route('app.verEquipo', $product->url) .'">
                <div class="row espacioRowBusca">'.
                    '<div class="col-2 center"><img src='. asset("{$product->fotoPNG}") .' alt="" class="imgBuscador"></div>'.
                    '<div class="col-10">
                        <h3>'.$product->name.'</h3>
                        <p>'.Str::limit($product->descBusqueda, 100).'</p>'
                        . $img
                    .'</div>'.
                '</div>
            </a>';
            } // end foreach
```

Por otra parte, creo que sobra un `asset()` y debería ser solo `asset('images/logos/fda-mio.svg')`

Comment: Hola @Triby , funciona perfecto como siempre. Eres un genio! solo cambio lo del asset que comentabas, es cierto se me colo, ahora se queda así: `? '<img src="'. asset("images/logos/fda-mio.svg") .'" alt="" class="imgBuscador">'`